# Kendo Dropdownlist inside a kendo grid does not open when clicking on the icon in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo dropdown list in Kendo Grid for bulk editing. But when I click on the side Icon in an IE Browser my dropdown doesn't open. In other browsers, e.g. Chrome/Mozilla, it opens properly.

Is that a Kendo Dropdownlist issue with IE Browser?

Comment: no thats not issue of Kendo UI. I am using Kendo grid for Ajax. and working fyn

Comment: Does the console give you any warnings, I could imagine there might be an error in the databound event or the open event

Comment: You should provide your code first, no one can precisely tell what's the problem without seeing your code